# How to bounce with an external effect in Adobe Audition

Tags: effects

I have **an external effect**, accessible as a VST plug-in. Everything works fine when working with my session; but **when I want to bounce my session, it's not done in realtime**, so my bounce is completely silent. And trying to route the mix to a bus with the idea of recording it, the recording button is not there!

I'm stuck with using one of these solutions: a software audio loopback, a hardware audio loopback, or a VST recorder insert.

Any other idea?

Comment: I would have added the following tags to the question, but my reputation is not sufficient: "audition bounce real-time"

Comment: Bouncing the tracks simply completes the same processing at the most rapid rate the computer's configuration can offer. Does your plugin only control the external effect? IOW, is the audio processing of the external effect done in some other box with automatable control knobs being the VST?

Comment: phasetransitions: the audio processing is only done in realtime outside of the application, without automation.

Comment: There is no "realtime" switch for bouncing in Audition? Cubase does have one.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new channel, set it up to RESAMPLE and bounce the track. 
Just don't forget to raise your master volume, since the Resample will capture the master sound.